# scrapy shell appears different as user interface, portion of the website is not scrapeable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

The problem is I cannot scrape portion of website. If I use Chrome devmode, I cannot copy the correct position, either in xpath or selector.

I would get correct path for other tabs or divs for example the body header: `body > div.header.home-header > div`

whereas when I'm trying to get the tab with information I want, I only got: `#htmlContent`. If I write it manually it should be: `body > div.main.main-top.seach-boxstyle > div > div > div.recommend-product-wrap.produc-text > div > div.recommend-product`, but that returned a empty list.

I'm thinking about if someone make the whole session cited so I cannot scrape, or it's another issue. The URL is in Chinese though: http://www.usewealth.com/Product/More.aspx?productDisplay=isArticle

I'm trying to help a company to scrape its own recommended swaps list, whereas the list is not appear in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the page renders its content dynamically using JavaScript. Scrapy itself doesn't run JavaScript, it only downloads the HTML source of the page, thus the dynamic content is not there. There are basically two options what to do in such case. Either render the page using some headless browser (e.g. Selenium or Splash) and let Scrapy parse the rendered result. From my experience, I would recommend using Splash because it's more reliable and the integration with Scrapy is seamless using [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) library.

The other option is to use browser's developer tools to look if the page doesn't use an API to get the data (which JavaScript then renders on the page). This seems to be the case with the website you are trying to scrape. Looking into Chrome developer tools (network tab and then XHR requests), I see POST requests to this URL:

```
http://www.usewealth.com/Action/ProductAJAX.ashx
```

It returns a JSON response which seems to contain all the needed data and which you can parse using standard `json` library.

Comment: Hi but while I use post I could only get a status 200 returned

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem with status 200? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: How can I request the content inside of the ashx i.e. the json response. I'm still not quite getting it, thanks for replying

Comment: You define [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method in your spider and inside the method, you `yield` `scrapy.Request` with POST method and parameters you infer from browser's developer tools. There's plenty of SO questions/answers that cover this.